# How to to use laravel WhereIn with two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables (`cards` and `composed_card`).

The first table is the `cards` table, which contains multiple cards with IDs(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....).

The second table is `card_compositions`, which contains three columns (`composed_card` and `used_card`).

In the second table both `composed_card` and `used_card` are foreign keys to `cards` table.

I'm trying to write a query in Laravel to get all `cards` that has at least one `composed_card` in `card_compositions` table.

I'm trying to create this query in Laravel Eloquent.

```
select * from `cards` where `id` in (select `composed_card` from `card_compositions` where `composed_card` = cards.id) and `cards`.`deleted_at` is null
```

The above SQL query works fine and returns the required results.

When I try to execute the same query in Laravel, it's not returning any results:

```
return Card::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query->select('composed_card')
        ->from('card_compositions')
        ->where('composed_card', '=', 'cards.id');
});
```

I wrote the above code to simulate the SQL query, but the above code is not working.

What I'm possibly doing wrong in the php code?

Comment: Are you missing a `get`? i.e. `whereIn(....)->get()` ?

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: Why don't you use of join statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `WhereRaw`. Explanation and code:

Your code is currently trying to find a match for the string 'cards.id', not join on the table cards.id. If you do

```
DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log
\\Run your query with ->get()
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Then you will see:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `cards` where `id` in (select `composed_card` from `card_compositions` where `composed_card` = ?)"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "cards.id"
    ]
    "time" => 4.48
  ]
]
```

Note your query now has a binding, your raw query takes no parameters. Your id column is integer, and its trying to find the string "cards.id" inside it, which it never will, which explains why you get no results.  So replace with:

```
return Card::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query->select('composed_card')
        ->from('card_compositions')
        ->whereRaw('composed_card = cards.id'); \\new WhereRaw clause
});
```

If you dump that, you will get the raw query you're expecting, and running it will get the results back.